# Minimize Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want Selenium to work in the background.

```
DRIVER=webdriver.Chrome('/Applications/chromedriver')
driver.minimize_window()
```

But then I can't use following code:

```
ActionChains(DRIVER).move_by_offset(10,10).click().perform() # Clicks on a specific area, I can't work with xpath here.
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run selenium in background, Please use headless mode.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
DRIVER= webdriver.Chrome(/Applications/chromedriver, options=options)
```

then you can write this line of **code**

```
ActionChains(DRIVER).move_by_offset(10,10).click().perform()
```

**with bit modification :**

```
ActionChains(DRIVER).move_by_offset(10,10).pause(2).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

If don't want the Chrome web browser window to appear when performing a web scrape easiest option is run it in headless mode.  In this mode, the Chrome web browser will run without any graphical user interface, and you still can use the API to click buttons, and submit form actions, etc.

```python
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
pathToChromeDriver = '/Applications/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=pathToChromeDriver,
                          options=options)
```

When you're debugging the Python code and need to show the content in the web browser, comment out the headless option, but when it is working and ready to run in the background then enable headless mode.